# Turn ubuntu 14.4 to a reverse proxy

Tags: proxy

have 2 Vps with ubuntu Linux OS the first one is DDos Protected and the other one is not. and im running a game server in the non protected Vps and i want to use the Protected VPS as a DDOS shield for the game server. I tried to use HAProxy and socat but i failed to do that in all the ports. anyone got ideas about doing that with ip tables or with any other program in ubuntu 14.4 ? im using 3 main ports in my game server and i want to protect. I just wanted the protected VPS to act like the main game server. the ports im using in my game server is 7171 & 7173 & 80. Thanks in advance.